# State space model of a PWM driven circuit

Tags: mosfet, pwm, matlab, modeling, state-space

I am trying to write down the state space model of the circuit given below:

[image]

As it can be seen above, a P channel mosfet transistor is driven by a PWM signal. I am trying to model the circuit parameters for one period of the PWM signal. However, I dont know how to determine the boundary values of the parameters when the mosfet turns from on to off and vice versa. When the mosfet is on, I consider it to be a short circuit. Also, I consider the diodes D1 and D2 to be short circuits and the diode D3 to be a circuit break. Below is a picture of that circuit:

[image]

I determined the state space model of the circuit above to be:

$${di_1(t)\over dt} = {{V_{in}-R_1i_1(t)-R_2i_2(t)-V_{c_2}(t)}\over L_1}\tag1$$
$${dV_{c_2}(t)\over dt} = {i_2(t)\over C_2}\tag2$$
$${di_3(t)\over dt} ={{R_2i_2(t)+V_{c_2}(t)-R_3i_3(t)}\over L_3} \tag3$$
$$i_1(t) = i_2(t) + i_3(t)\tag4$$

When the mosfet is not conducting, I consider it to be a circuit break. The diodes D1 and D2 are still modeled as a short circuit, and so is the diode D3. The picture of that circuit is given below:

[image]

I determined the state space model of the circuit above to be:

$${di_1(t)\over dt} = {{V_{in}-R_1i_1(t)-R_2i_2(t)-V_{c_2}(t)}\over L_1}\tag5$$
$${dV_{c_2}(t)\over dt} = {i_2(t)\over C_2}\tag6$$
$${di_3(t)\over dt} =-{{R_3i_3(t)}\over L_3} \tag7$$
$$i_1(t)=i_2(t)\tag8$$

My question is, what happens to the the currents *i1(t)* and *i2(t)* when the mosfet transitions from on to off and vice versa. From the last picture it is obvious that the current *i1(t)* and *i2(t)* are the same since they are in the same branch, but at the boundary moment should I consider those currents to differ? If yes, then how do they differ? If not, does the current *i2(t)* become *i1(t)* or is it the other way around?

Also what happens to the voltage on the capacitor (and why) when the mosfet transitions from on to off and vice versa?

Thank you for your time and attention. I would be grateful for your help. I need to solve this for a numerical simulation in Matlab.

Comment: State space generally means that we need to use the minimum number of state variables. I think that you can avoid the variable \$i_2\$ altogether. For the first circuit replace all \$i_2\$ with \$i_1 - i_3\$. In the second one, replace all \$i_2\$ with \$i_1\$.

Comment: Don't forget that when the transistor is off, the body diode conducts.